# How do you get the JavaScript fetch() function to update to the new data being added to the file

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I have a JSON file containing some data that i want to write to the screen. I have a function that contains a fetch() request that runs each time i click a button. This works great the first time i click the button as it takes the data and outputs it correctly. But once the JSON file gets new content added to it and i press the same button for a second time during the same session all the data is the exact same as the first time it was run. And i know for a fact that the code after the fetch() is ran (the console.log(data.lenght);). I've read a bunch about the Fetch API but i havent been able to find something to help with this. I've also read on another thread that the fetch() function only runs once but the code after always runs, seemingly confirming my problem.

```
function fetchJSON() {

    fetch("static/json/pool_values.json")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.length);
```

Comment: _"I've also read on another thread that the fetch() function only runs once"_ If you call it once, sure, but if you call it multiple times, it will definitely run as many times. Maybe you've got cache? What happens if you use this as the URL: `"static/json/pool_values.json?t=" + Date.now()` ?

Comment: Sounds like it is an issue with the cache, What happens if you update your call to `fetch("static/json/pool_values.json", {cache: 'no-cache'})`? [Fetch API options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch)

Comment: @blex I tried your solution but sadly nothing changed, thanks though

Comment: @peinearydevelopment I'll look into it further but it didn't work sorry

Comment: @peinearydevelopment Update: Your solution works but only every other time. So my data.length changes from 9 -> 9 -> 11 - > 11 -> 13 etc.

Comment: sorry, looks like it should be `no-store`, not `no-cache` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem as though there is an issue with your cache.
This can be fixed by passing an option to your request.

```
fetch("static/json/pool_values.json", {cache: 'no-store'})
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.length);
```

Comment: Your solution works but only every other time. So my data.length changes from 9 -> 9 -> 11 - > 11 -> 13 etc.